# Вывести все запущенные процессы Windows

Tags: python

Я хочу с помощью python вывести все запущенные процессы что-бы в них присутствовали PID,Название и Уровень доступа.
Нашел такое решение

```
for proc in psutil.process_iter(['pid', 'name', 'username']):
      print(proc.info)
      file = open('file.txt', 'w+')
      file.write(proc.info)
```

Но не могу записать в файл ошибка

```
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not dict
```

при попытке

```
file.write(str(proc.info))
```

в файл записывает только последний элемент

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение в стиле Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([proc.info  for proc in psutil.process_iter(['pid', 'name', 'username'])])
df.to_csv("c:/temp/processes.csv", sep=";", index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так:

```
with open('c:/temp/file.txt', 'w+') as f:
    for proc in psutil.process_iter(['pid', 'name', 'username']):
        print('{name}\t{pid}\t{username}'.format(proc.info), file=f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто нужно открывать файл не в "режиме записи"

```py
file = open('file.txt', 'w')
```

Потому что в этом режиме файл полностью перезаписывается.

А нужно открывать файл в "режиме добавления"

```py
file = open('file.txt', 'a')
```

Второй аргумент должен быть `'a'`. Тогда файл будет ДОПОЛНЯТЬСЯ, а не перезаписываться. И будут сохраняться все процессы.